# What is the size of smallest flute?

Tags: flute

As far as you know ,what is the  size of the  smallest flute ? ( You might have come across different sized flutes)

Comment: Would you include instruments like piccolo?

Comment: Interesting question.  I would include the piccolo but I would be curious whether there are piccolos even smaller than the standard ones.  I have heard of a Db piccolo which would qualify but only just.

Comment: Have a look at this article.  A flute pitched an octave above the standard piccolo.  http://jennifercluff.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/piccolo-fourth-octave-exist.html

Comment: @Tim , Yes,I include your instrument,music lovers are broadminded,they do not look /consider anything or any person as inferior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once upon a time, the term flute (flauto) properly referred to what is today called a recorder (also known as a type of fipple flute). If you'll accept a recorder as a possible answer, the smallest recorder I know of is the [Garklein](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garklein_recorder) (German for "quite small"), which is only 16-18 cm.

Comment: That explains why the French for flute proper is 'flute traversiere'. Which I thought was pretty daft, as all flutes are sideways - aren't they? I learned something new again today. Thanks! +1

Comment: @ Caleb Hines , I am thrilled by reading about 16 cm size

Comment: as far as I know, the recorder is still referred to as a flauto dolce

Comment: @user48608 if a recorder is an acceptable solution the 'tin whistle' aka 'penny whistle' should be too, and it's smaller too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_whistle

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in recorders and are looking just for transverse flutes, the smallest common flutes available are either the piccolo or the fife with both being about 30cm in length.

There are a number of other transverse flutes including the bansuri, venu, dizi, fue, daegeum, junggeum and sogeum but given that these are traditional flutes not from the west, information online on their dimensions seems to be lacking. However, from looking at pictures none of these appear to be noticeably shorter than the piccolo or fife.

Given that a transverse flute is essentially a pipe with holes drilled into it, I can imagine many people have made smaller transverse flutes for the fun of it. [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOptwNarAoc), it sounds terrible but with some effort and a slightly longer pipe something workable surely could be created.